# Backbone collection's fetch method not calling?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

i am using yoeman scaffolding to create and build a Backbone project. i am trying below code unable to fetch collection's data in view's initialize block. i am not getting any error in console. i tried to debug but it's not going in success block. can you anyone tell me the correct way to consume collection in Backbone View.

contacts.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "first name",
        "mobile": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
        "email": "anshuls@abc.com"
          },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second name",
        "mobile": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
        "email": "anshuls@abc.com"
          }
     ]
```

//model

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({      
        initialize: function() {

        },

        defaults: {
            name:null,            
            mobile:null,
            email:null,
            avatar:null
        }    

    });

    return ContactModel;
});
```

//collection

```
    define([
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'models/contact'], function (_, Backbone, ContactModel) {
        'use strict';

        var ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: ContactModel,
            url: 'scripts/json/contacts.json',
            initialize: function () {
            }       
        });

        return ContactCollection;
    });
```

//view

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'templates',
    '../views/contact',
     '../collections/contact'
], function ($, _, Backbone, JST, ContactView, ContactCollection) {
    'use strict';

    var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/contacts.hbs'],          
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.collection = new ContactCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function (collection,response) {
                    console.log('Collection fetch success' + response);
                    console.log('Collection models: ' + collection.models);

                }
            });
        }
    })
    return ContactsView;
});
```

Comment: Try adding this `parse: function(response) { return response; }` - Sometimes Backbone needs to pass the .json file through a parse method.

Comment: it's not going in parse block of collection, but initialize block is calling on collection object creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error block to your collection.fetch, and see if the error block is being called:

```
this.collection.fetch({
                success: function (collection,response) {
                    console.log('Collection fetch success' + response);
                    console.log('Collection models: ' + collection.models);

                },
                error: function(model, xhr, options) {
                    console.log('error'); <-- debug here
                }
            });
```

Comment: it's not even going in error block i have tried, i think fetch is not calling properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the collection actually make the request for the data? do you see it in the network tab?

Comment: yes i saw it's not making ajax call for data. there is no request in network tab.